# How to evaluate Polymer 1.0 published on Google i/o 2015?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, frontend

Will it be widely used in front-end engineering?
How to evaluate the potential of Polymer 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Polymer, but it's clear that it'll not become the authority in front-end engineering, specially with Angular 2.0 going it's own custom way of building components, and React having it's own opinion on solving the same problems that Polymer solves.

One thing I do see is that [Web Components](http://webcomponents.org/) are definitely gaining traction, specially the shadow-dom which is embraced by both Polymer and Angular 2.0 Components.

Also, though future frameworks will support web components Eg.Angular 2.0 , and Polymer elements or any other library written on top of the web components spec, can be used with such frameworks, it wouldn't really make sense in doing so, as then you'll have to carry the weight of Polymer on top of your primary framework like Angular/React, which doesn't make sense as both frameworks solve essentially the same problems in their own opinionated way.

Comment: Great answer, very specific ! Thank you!